# Dynamically add @ContentChild element to a specific div inside the parent component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add the @ContentChild element (using directive) to be added to a div inside the component template? HTML templates are given below for reference.

app-component.html:

```html
<app-root>

    <a-component>
        <div a-directive>
        </div>
    </a-component>

</app-root>
```

a-component.html:

```html
<div>
    Title
</div>

<div #container>
    <!-- place holder for a-directive element -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `<ng-content>` tag. Try the following

a-component.html:

```html
<div>
  Title
</div>

<div #container>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

app-component.html:

```html
<app-root>
  <a-component>
    <div a-directive></div>
  </a-component>
</app-root>
```

The statements inside the `<a-component>` selector will be rendered in the `<ng-content>` of the a-component.

Comment: I understand ng-content can be used here. But, as I understand, ng-content tag should be present in the template. My requirement is creating dynamic placeholders, say, using ngFor, and adding these a-directive elements to the placeholders.